# Error using ==> mtimes MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging

I am trying to numerically integrate a function on MATLAB (I am on MATLAB 7.7). Here is my code.

```
fun = @(t)(cos(t)./sqrt(3)-sin(t)).^39*(cos(t)./sqrt(3)+sin(t)).^63*sqrt(2*cos(t).^2 + 2/3*sin(t).^2);
quad(fun,-pi/6,pi/6)
```

Unfortunately I am not following the error message. Can anyone help me please?

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==>
@(t)(cos(t)./sqrt(3)-sin(t)).^39*cos(t)./sqrt(3)+sin(t)).^63*sqrt(2*cos(t).^2+2/3*sin(t).^2)


Error in ==> quad at 77
y = f(x, varargin{:});
```

I have tried to see if the function definition is right. It seems to work for me:

```
fun(1)
ans =

-1.4078e-007
```

which the correct value I would expect when evaluated at 1. I have done several trials with various inputs, the function fun() seems to compute them alright!

p.s.: I have used quad() before this. It has worked well for me previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works for scalar inputs, but not for vectors:

```
>> fun(1:5)
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

You need to change your function to do elementwise multiplication:

```
fun = @(t)(cos(t)./sqrt(3)-sin(t)).^39.*(cos(t)./sqrt(3)+sin(t)).^63.*sqrt(2*cos(t).^2 + 2/3.*sin(t).^2);
```

Comment: I see - I forgot that 2/3 needs be dot-multiplied. I am used to thinking 2/3 as a scalar. Right. Very subtle. Thanks you very much!